# using variable inside the awk command

Tags: shell-script, awk

Im trying to

```
for ds in $(cat Nikhil/strings.txt )
do
awk -v k="$ds" '{if (substr($0,2,5) == k )print $0}' criteria5.txt
done
```

but when i execute this it is taking the value of k as k instead of the variable . Shell check .net is not working so had to post this here

```
+ for ds in '$(cat Nikhil/strings.txt )'

+ awk -v k=CDA01 '{if (substr($0,2,5) == k )print $0}' criteria5.txt
```

This is how the output is when i tried to debug using sh -x . Any suggestions please

Comment: but this lines says it doesn't `+ awk -v k=CDA01 '{if (substr($0,2,5) == k )print $0}' criteria5.txt`, see `k=CDA01`; also [do not use shell-loops for text-processing purposes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/72456)

Comment: It is calling the variable CDA01 from the file , but inside the if condition it is substituting as k

Comment: no, it doesn't you can verify it by printing `if (substr($0,2,5) == k )print k, $0}`;

Comment: is the code wrong ?

Comment: @Nikhil I can see nothing wrong with your code. The shell would not substitute `k` with anything inside the `awk` code for the purpose of showing it in the `set -x` trace output, but you can rest assured that `-v k="$ds"` will _definitely_ make the value of the `k` variable that of `$ds` in the shell. If the code does what you want it to do, none of us can tell.  In this case though, it may be more convenient to _not_ use a shell loop and instead use a more sophisticated `awk` command (which would be _much_ quicker).

Comment: Thanks for the @Kusalananda. can you elaborate what is the sophisticated awk command. If you can give me a lead i will try to dig in

Comment: @Nikhil There are many examples of similar issues. See e.g. [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106645), [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/432115), [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159961) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41065) (but really, this is a very common issue (performing a relational JOIN between two files) and the solution is always on the same form, unless one could use `join` as I in my answer to that last example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce what's happening in your codes but I see all is syntaxically fine and working; but here is what you seems are trying to do with shell-loops that you would better to [avid it](/q/169716/72456). Below I used `awk` command alone.

```
gawk 'ARGIND==2{ strings[$0]; next; };
     (substr($0, 2, 5) in strings);
' RS='[[:space:]]+' strings.txt RS='\n' criteria.txt
```

Here we are reading all strings (split on whitespaces or `\n`ewline `[[:space:]]` in *"strings.txt"* file into an `awk` associated array (we name it `strings`).

The `ATGIND==2` controlling the input and to run first block of the code only for the *"strings.txt"* file and *awk* will skip running that block for next input(s). see here [why we preferred this over more common use of `NR==FNR`](/a/237110/72456).

when next file *"criteria.txt"* opened for processing, we set Record Separator to default `\n`ewline in `RS='\n'`; and in `(substr($0, 2, 5) in strings)` we are checking if the expected *`substr`ing* start from position *2* with character length of *5* exist in our array or not, if it was, then the line will go to output .

Input data:
`strings.txt`:

```
CDA01 CDA02
   CDA03
CDA03    CDA05 CDA06
```

`criteria.txt`:

```
xCDA01 something
xxCDA02 someotherthing
CDA01
vcCDA03 oCDA03
vCDA05 end
```

Output:

```
xCDA01 something
vCDA05 end
```